# WPF Get Control Associated with Validation Error

Tags: wpf, validation, controls

I'm building a control that operates like a validation summary control. When it displays the list of validation errors, I would like the user to be able to click on an error and then move focus to the actual control associated with the error.

I am trying to figure out how to pull that off.

How do I get the specific UI control associated with a specific error in Validation.Errors?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to handle the Validation.Error attached event. From there it was easy to get the DependencyObject (control) that was the source of the error.

MSDN Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.error(v=vs.110).aspx